# java.net.SocketException Error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, serversocket

I created a SOA service with Socket Adapter on JDeveloper and I need to run/test it using Java. So I created a server class and a client class but I am getting an error

I did some research on how to create this service and test it and I came across some helpful material online but yet I'm getting an error and I dont know how to fix it. I am very new to making socket servers and stuff.

here is my server class

```
package client;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Class1 {

      try {

        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(12110);
    Socket s=socket.accept();

          System.out.println("Connected!");

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
}
```

and here is my client class

```
package client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.net.Socket;

public class Client{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
              Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 12110);
              OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
              os.write("FirstName,LastName\nWaslley,Souza\nJohn,Snow".getBytes());
              os.flush();
              socket.shutdownOutput();
              BufferedReader soc_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
              String response = soc_in.readLine();
              System.out.println("Response: " + response);
              socket.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

here is the error I get:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at client.Client.main(Client.java:23)
```

Comment: This is an application protocol error, as is often the case. Merely accepting a connection and then exiting is bound to upset the client. Your client is sending something. The server need to read it. Your client is reading something. The server needs to send it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your server code exits after accepting a socket connection. Consequently, the JVM of this server will exit and (among others) close all socket connections it holds. This results in a `SocketException` on the client side.

To fix this, you should prevent the server's JVM from exiting, for instance by nesting the `accept()` call in a `while` loop:

```
public class Server {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(12110);
      while (true) {
        Socket s = socket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected! to " + s);
      }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not quite. It results in a `connection reset` *because the server hasn't read the pending data*. If there was no pending data it would have resulted in an orderly close.

Comment: This is not what I'm seeing. After making sure all data is read from the incoming connection, the `SocketException: Connection reset` is still raised. What am I missing?

Comment: It depends on the platform. Windows will reset unclosed sockets. Unix and Linux will close them properly unless there is unread pending data, when it will reset. However exiting without closing is always wrong, and closing without reading all the pending data ditto.

Comment: I tried this and although I am not getting any error now, the client side doesn't show any response. On the server side I get the success message

Comment: @Mike The code doesn't contain the important part where the server actually reads from the socket and writes a reply, or closes it. It is not an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Server Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Class1 {

    //static ServerSocket variable
    private static ServerSocket server;
    //socket server port on which it will listen
    private static int port = 12110;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        //create the socket server object
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        //keep listens indefinitely until receives 'exit' call or program terminates
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting for the client request");
            //creating socket and waiting for client connection
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            //read from socket to ObjectInputStream object
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //convert ObjectInputStream object to String
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
            //create ObjectOutputStream object
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            //write object to Socket
            oos.writeObject("Hi Client " + message);
            //close resources
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            socket.close();
            //terminate the server if client sends exit request
            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");
        //close the ServerSocket object
        server.close();
    }

}
```

Client Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        //get the localhost IP address, if server is running on some other IP, you need to use that
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket socket = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        //establish socket connection to server
        socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 12110);
        //write to socket using ObjectOutputStream
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Sending request to Socket Server");

        oos.writeObject("SEND SOME DATA");
        //read the server response message
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        String message = (String) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("Message: " + message);
        //close resources
        ois.close();
        oos.close();
        Thread.sleep(100);

    }
}
```

do in this way.

Comment: He is using lines, not objects.

Comment: Yea can u please demonstrate it using the lines. I have this line os.write("FirstName,LastName\nWaslley,Souza\nJohn,Snow".getBytes()); and I want it to work and for me to get a proper response..

Comment: @Mike If you have that, you have the problem that you're reading lines but not sending lines. Use `println()`, or add a line terminator to the message.

Answer (score 0):

yo @Mike sorry was not clear last time dig in this is the full server code

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;
public class Serv1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Serv1().start();
    }
    public void start(){
        String input = "";
            try(ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(12110)) {
                System.out.println("Connected!");
                while (true) {
                try(Socket server = socket.accept()){
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                    PrintStream echo = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());
                    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null && !input.equals(".")) {
                        System.out.println(input);
                        echo.println("Echoed: " + input);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it

```
        String input= "";
        Socket server=socket.accept();
        BufferedReader  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        PrintStream echo = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());
        while((input = in.readLine()) != null && !input.equals(".")) {
            System.out.println(input);
            echo.println("echo: "+input);
        }
```

Comment: Do I write this on client or server side? Because I entered this on the client side and i got an unexpected error on accept()

Comment: @Mike This is server code. The `accept()` tells you that. However the poster should certainly have explained his code. Mere code is not an answer here.

Comment: so I put the code in server and in response I got the first line of the message not the rest. Is there a way to get the rest?

Comment: @user207421 I think this one sort of worked.. But its only reading the first line. is there a way to make it read the entire message?

Comment: @Mike sorry i was not clear last time hear is the full code